# Replace useless parts of code

Tags: scheme

I have to implement a program which finds useless parts of code and replace its with some better code. I'll give you an example:

```
;;(define (positive-odd? n)
;;  (if (and (odd? n) (positive? n)) #t #f))
```

should be replaced with:

```
;;(define (positive-odd? n)
;;  (and (odd? n) (positive? n)))
```

I also have a list with rules. I'll give you an example of a rule which will help us for the the example from bellow:

```
;;(define redundant-if
;;  '((WHEN (if ?cond #t #f))
;;    (THEN ?cond)))
```

So, I have to iterate on this list of rules and find matching between rules and my function with useless code. To do that I have only an idea, but I don't think it's a good one: I take very rule from the list of rules, then I iterate on the body of my function and look up for similarities and when I find one, I replace the code. But I think it's quite difficult to do this.

Please give me any idea of this problem's implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is called **partial evaluation**;

Examples such as using rewrite rules to simplify algebraic expressions can be found in [A Hacker's Introduction to Partial Evaluation](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://wry.me/misc/peval.html)